# How to solve recursive higher-order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $L(L(y)) = 0$ where, $ L(y) = y^{(n)} + y$ for any $ y(t) \in C^{(n)}(\mathbb{R})$?

If I expand 
$$L(L(y)) = (y^{(n)}+y)^{(n)} + y^{(n)} + y = y^{(2n)} + 2y^{(n)} + y$$
then I don't even know if $y^{(n)}(t)$ is further differentiable.

If I try compute characteristic polynomial I get $\lambda^n=-1$, what has complex solutions, but I'm working on the polynomial of the regular expression, not the one calling itself.

Comment: How is $L(L(y))=0$ well-defined if there is no guarantee that $y^{(n)}$ is differentiable further?

Comment: Note $(y^{(n)})^{(n)} = y^{(2n)}.$  Can you use the Laplace transform?

Comment: @Dzoooks I had never used Laplace transform, but with some properties I got to $\mathcal{L}\{y\}(s^n+1)^2=0$. I seem to misunderstand something.

Comment: Solutions of linear homogeneous ordinary differential equations with constant coefficients can be expressed as linear combinations of the products of $e^{\alpha t}$, $t^k$, $\sin(\beta t)$ and $\cos(\beta t)$, so they are real analytic and can be differentiated as many times as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation is
$$
\bigl(\lambda^n+1\bigr)^2=0.
$$
It has $n$ double roots, the $n$-th roots of $-1=e^{\pi i}$, which are
$$
e^{\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{n}+\tfrac{2k\pi}{n}\bigr)i}=\cos\Bigl(\frac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\Bigr)+i\sin\Bigl(\frac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\Bigr),\quad 0\le k\le n-1.
$$
This gives $2\,n$ independent solutions for $0\le k\le n-1$:
$$
e^{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\bigr)t}\cos\Bigl(\sin\Bigl(\frac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\Bigr)\,t\Bigr),\quad
e^{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\bigr)t}\sin\Bigl(\sin\Bigl(\frac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\Bigr)\,t\Bigr),\\
t\,e^{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\bigr)t}\cos\Bigl(\sin\Bigl(\frac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\Bigr)\,t\Bigr),\quad
t\,e^{\cos\bigl(\tfrac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\bigr)t}\sin\Bigl(\sin\Bigl(\frac{(2\,k+1)\pi}{n}\Bigr)\,t\Bigr).
$$
The general solution is a linear combination of them.